# Unable to show excerpts

Tags: excerpt

Looking to have post excerpts show.

I cannot find 
 
in index.php file, archive.php file, or category.php
Have even tried coping the code out and searching it using Word.

Any suggestions?

Theme: paperback (periodical in wordpress premium)
I want excerpts under the posts. This is a photo of how it used to be set up before I migrated to self- hosted, this is what I want back. Right now it shows the first couple lines of the post instead of the excerpt.
[image]

Comment: what theme are you using?

Comment: Where do you want the excerpts to appear?

Comment: My theme is called Paperback (or Periodical if purchased through wordpress premium) and I want the excerpts directly under the posts in the grid.